# Mysql queries for column type date

Tags: php, mysql, date

How can I get records with

1. Todays Date
2. Yesterdays Date
3. Last 7 Days
4. Last 30 Days
5. This Month
6. Last Month

I am using a date field. Not datetime. date field like YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: a MySQL date field is like YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I am not sure, it is the default mysql date format. But that is how dates are stored 2011-04-04  so I guess it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `SELECT ... WHERE DATE(datetimefield) = CURDATE()`
2. `SELECT ... WHERE DATE(datetimefield) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`
3. `SELECT ... WHERE DATE(datetimefield) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`
4. `SELECT ... WHERE DATE(datetimefield) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`
5. `SELECT ... (WHERE YEAR(datetimefield) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND (MONTH(datetimefield) = MONTH(CURDATE())`
6. left as an exercise to the reader... (hint: see #5)

Comment: My friend, people like you are the reason, I can keep coming back to stack overflow and be motivated to learn more or ask more. Although it may be stupid or selfish at times but it is just good to see, how some people are so helpful. Thanks mate....I just want you to post another comment, so just I can upvote it. So many thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a lot of date related functions, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Of course your date field has to be a date field, which doesn't seem to be the case now.

Comment: I really need help with the queries, as I need the code really quick...sorry if I am being rude, but I really haven't got time to read that right now, but I definitely will in the future. But I really need the queries. Hope you can understand. :(

Comment: Yes, I understand you don't want to learn but you want a job done right now. We are not slaves, but you might want to pay someone to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to calculate date you need in php then try

```
Select * from tbl where coldate = '$myphpdate'
```

Comment: Also somewhat racey in the case where you generate the date at 11:59:59pm in PHP, but the query doesn't execute until 12:00:01 the next day in MySQL

Comment: @Marc - there will always be a race condition somewhere. If you do it in SQL there is a race condition

Comment: Actually, no. In ACID compliant databases, single statements are atomic. Generating the date within the query with `...where coldate=curdate()` is guaranteed to produce the proper results.